# What is the best way to validate association in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two associated models: `Apartment` and `Lessor`. And I need to be able to create `Lessor` from `Apartment` form.

In `Apartment` model:

```
belongs_to :lessor
before_save :save_lessor
...
def lessor_cellphone= val
  @cellphone = val
end
...
private
def save_lessor
  if Lessor.exists? :cellphone => @cellphone
    self.lessor = Lessor.find_by_cellphone @cellphone
  else
    self.create_lessor :cellphone => @cellphone
  end
  @cellphone = nil
end
```

In `Lessor` model:

```
validates :cellphone, :format => {:with => /\d{11}/}, :uniqueness => true
has_many :apartments, :dependent => :nullify
```

But when I trying to create `Apartment` with invalid `cellphone`, `Lessor` is not created becouse validation fails, but `Apartment is created.

What is the best way to validate `cellphone` (and maybe more) and rise error in the `Apartment` form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think maybe a better solution would be to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to create a nested model through the form of an other.

See http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 or http://asciicasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 for the text version.

Nontheless, if you want to use your existing solution:
If you return `false` in a `before_*` callback all the later callbacks and the associated action are cancelled, see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

So I guess it would be something like

```
def create_lessor(data)
  # validate data here
  return false if # data not valid
end

def save_lessor
  rc = true
  if Lessor.exists? :cellphone => @cellphone
    self.lessor = Lessor.find_by_cellphone @cellphone
  else
    rc = self.create_lessor(:cellphone => @cellphone)
  end
  @cellphone = nil
  rc  # return the return code
end
```

It's not a beautiful solution AT ALL, but I think you get the idea...

Comment: Is it possible to associate apartment to existed lessor, if the lessor record with the cellphone already exists, by using 'accepts_nested_attributes_for'?

Comment: Of course. It makes no different if a new record is created or an existing record is updated. You just have to make sure to `build` it with the right record.